# $\dim Z(x_1x_2,x_2x_3,x_1x_3)=0$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension, affine-varieties

I need to compute $\dim Z(x_1x_2,x_2x_3,x_1x_3)$, in $\mathbb{A}_k^3$. I believe that this variety consists of the unique point $(0,0,0)$. So, its dimension is $0$. Am I correct? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The origin is in this variety, but there are a lot of other points, eg $(t,0,0)$ for  all $t\in k$.

Comment: Oh... great. Thank you! So... $Z(x_1x_2,x_2x_3,x_1x_3)=Z(x_1x_2,x_2x_3)\cap Z(x_1x_3)=(Z(x_1,x_3)\cap Z(x_1,x_3))\cup (Z(x_2) \cap Z(x_1,x_3))=Z(x_2) \cap Z(x_1,x_3)$. The first dimension is $1$, the second $2$, so the dimension is $2$...?

Comment: Your computation is wrong, $x_2$ needs not be $0$.

Comment: $Z(x_1x_2,x_2x_3)\cap Z(x_1x_3)=(Z(x_2)\cup Z(x_1,x_3))\cap Z(x_1x_3)=(Z(x_2)\cap Z(x_1x_3))\cup (Z(x_1,x_3)\cap Z(x_1x_3))=(Z(x_2)\cap Z(x_1x_3))\cup Z(x_1,x_3)$.                The last has dimension $1$. Once there are infinite many points as Isaac said, the dimension cannot be zero. So, the dimension is 1... ? Many thanks @ArnaudMortier

Comment: Do you know what this variety looks like? Once you know that you can determine the dimension by looking at the tangent spaces at the non-singular points.

Comment: Is the union of axis, @Isaac? Thank you!

Comment: $ Z (x_1x_2, x_2x_3, x_1x_3) = Z (x_1x_2) \cap Z (x_2x_3) \cap Z (x_1x_3). $
    
     This means that the variety considered is exactly the intersection of the coordinate planes, ie, the union of the three axes. Since axes have dimension $ 1 $, the variety has dimension $ 1 $.@Isaac, is it correct? Many thanks!

Comment: Exactly, it's the union of the three axis. You can see that this has an isolated singularity at the origin, and the tangent space at a non-singular point is a line, which has dimension 1, so the dimension of the variety is 1

Comment: @Isaac, thank you so much. Maybe could you post as an anwer, so I could accept. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collating what was in the comments, $X=V(xz,xy,yz)$ is the union of the coordinate axis, so has an isolated singularity at the origin. The tangent space at any non-singular point is therefore a line, which is one-dimensional, hence $\text{dim}\,X=1$.